# python: how to generate pairs of cards in a deck

Tags: python

Suppose that I have the following variables:

```
suits = ["h","c", "d", "s"]
cards = ["2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "t", "j", "q", "k", "a"]
deck = []

for suit in suits:
    for card in cards:
        deck.append(str(card+suit))
```

I'd like to write a function that, given a specific card, generates the possible combinations of pairs.

For instance, `generatePairs('a')` should return something like:

`['ahac','ahad','ahas','acad','acas','adas']`

but I'm not sure how to approach writing that function.

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations`

Comment: ah neat, can you point me towards which functions I'd use in this example?

Comment: `itertools.combinations` is a single function. It is the `combinations` function in the `itertools` module.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [7]: import itertools

In [8]: c = 'a'

In [9]: ['%s%s%s%s' % (c, s1, c, s2) for (s1, s2) in itertools.combinations(suits, 2)]
Out[9]: ['ahac', 'ahad', 'ahas', 'acad', 'acas', 'adas']
```

Answer (score 0):

you require something like

```
In [5]: deck = []

In [6]: for i in itertools.combinations(suits, 2):
   ...:     for j in cards:
   ...:         deck.append(j+i[0]+j+i[1])
   ...:

In [7]: print deck
['2h2c', '3h3c', '4h4c', '5h5c', '6h6c', '7h7c', '8h8c', '9h9c', 'thtc', 'jhjc', 'qhqc', 'khkc', 'ahac',
', '3h3d', '4h4d', '5h5d', '6h6d', '7h7d', '8h8d', '9h9d', 'thtd', 'jhjd', 'qhqd', 'khkd', 'ahad', '2h2s'
3s', '4h4s', '5h5s', '6h6s', '7h7s', '8h8s', '9h9s', 'thts', 'jhjs', 'qhqs', 'khks', 'ahas', '2c2d', '3c3
4c4d', '5c5d', '6c6d', '7c7d', '8c8d', '9c9d', 'tctd', 'jcjd', 'qcqd', 'kckd', 'acad', '2c2s', '3c3s', '4
 '5c5s', '6c6s', '7c7s', '8c8s', '9c9s', 'tcts', 'jcjs', 'qcqs', 'kcks', 'acas', '2d2s', '3d3s', '4d4s',
', '6d6s', '7d7s', '8d8s', '9d9s', 'tdts', 'jdjs', 'qdqs', 'kdks', 'adas']
```